# Why does throwing a std::exception by reference throw the base std::exception class instead of the derived class?

Tags: c++, exception, inheritance, std

OK, I am loosing it. I spent time on this but impossible to get the clue.

My tests program is below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class   SyntaxErrorException : public std::exception
{
    public:
        const char* what() const throw()
        {
            return ("SyntaxErrorException thrown");
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    SyntaxErrorException    s;
    std::exception&         e1 = s;
    std::exception&         e2 = e1;

    try
    {
        throw (s);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    try
    {
        throw (e1);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    try
    {
        throw (e2);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The output of this is:

```
Error: SyntaxErrorException thrown
Error: std::exception
Error: std::exception
```

One thing I know is that it's about ***object slicing*** in the two cases of `e1` and `e2`. But why and how?

Can someone help me understand what is literally happening in the "throw expression" line such that I get a basic `std::exception` object thrown?

The ultimate case is that I want to make a general function that takes as parameters a `std::string` custom error message and a `std::exception&` reference to the custom exception to be thrown.

Why can't I pass an object of my custom exception class by reference to a function that will throw that exception? Is there other ways?

Comment: Throw *always* throw a copy of the expression you gave it, which causes slicing. Imagine throw as a function `void throw_fn(auto);`. Also, please don't add extra parentheses everywhere, they causes confusion more than anything else.

Comment: You can't do it this way, because of slicing, like explained in the previous comment. However, maybe `auto exPtr = std::make_exception_ptr(SyntaxErrorException{});` and std::rethrow_exception(exPtr);` will work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a function template works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class SyntaxErrorException : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return ("SyntaxErrorException thrown");
    }
};

template<typename T>
void throwException(T& e)
{
    throw e;
}

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        SyntaxErrorException s;
        throwException(s);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
ERROR!
Error: SyntaxErrorException thrown
```

Comment: It's not a good example, because `T` is deduced as `SyntaxErrorException` so there is no slicing when making a copy. It's equivalent to just `throw SyntaxErrorException`. Question is about throwing `std::exception&` that references superclass object.

Comment: But yeah @pptaszni, you're right too, i was curious about that too.

Comment: @Anakin that's exactly what i did just after, it's the better way.